# How to loop over all the selected elements of an HTML page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-framework

I am working on a Quiz Application where I need to get all the selected elements or the user answers . These elements can be radio input, check-box input or the text field. every element is assigned a question_id attribute, answer_id and a mark attribute with it. What I want to do is I have to get these all question_id , answer_id and mark attribute so that I can calculate marks, and send the both question_id and answer_id to DB so that i can store the related user answer under a particular question. i have rendered the quiz on template using this code.

```
$(data.quiztopics).each(function(index,element){
    $(element.questions).each(function(index,question){
        $(".quiz").append("<form name='question' class= question_"+question.id+"><input type='text' disabled value="+question.question_text+"/><br></form>");
        if(question.question_type=='NUM'){
            $(question.answers).each(function(index,answer){
                $(".question_"+question.id).append("<input type='radio' question_id='+question.id+'answer_id='+answer.id +'name='answer' class=answer_"+answer.id+" mark="+answer.marks+"value="+answer.answer_text+">"+answer.answer_text+"</input>")
            });
        }
        else if(question.question_type=='MCQ'){
            $(question.answers).each(function(index,answer){
                $(".question_"+question.id).append("<input type='checkbox' question_id='+question.id+'answer_id='+answer.id +' name='answer' class=answer_"+answer.id+">"+answer.answer_text+"</input>")
            });
        }
        else if(question.question_type=='FIB'){
            $(question.answers).each(function(index,answer){
                $(".question_"+question.id).append("<input type='text' question_id='+question.id+'answer_id='+answer.id +' name='answer' class=answer_"+answer.id+">"+answer.answer_text+"</input>")
            });
        }
    });
});
```

tell me how can i get the attributes of the selected elements for submitting the quiz.

Comment: do you need the jquery selector which selects all the radio, checkboxes checked and the non empty textboxes?

Comment: No, Ayyappan Sekar, I want to select the selected answer fields to get the question_id and answer_id attributes. If i only  get these two attributes my task will be accomplished

Comment: i can help u if u share the rendered html of those quiz list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by getting all the elements available in the DOM by their name, using getElementsByName('answer') method. It returns me a list then looping over this list i checked if the element is check or not if it is checked i get their attributes.

```
attributes_list=new Array()
var answers=document.getElementsByName('answer');
for(i=0;i<answers.length;i++){
    if(answers[i].checked){
            question_id=answers[i].attributes['question_id'].value
            answer_id=answers[i].attributes['answer_id'].value
            attributes_list.push({'que':question_id,'ans':answer_id});
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do:

```
var questions = {};

$(".quiz :selected, .quiz :checked, .quiz input[type=text]").each({
   var $this = $(this);
   var question = $this.attr('question_id');
   questions[question] = {
       answer: $this.attr('class'),
   };
});
```

Comment: Hey jcubic, i have made some changes to the original question, i have removed the marks attribute from the input field because i found it a security whole. Now i just want to get the question_id and answer_id attribute of the selected input option. your help is appreciable

Answer (score 0):

its very simple, you just have to use `element.attr( attributeName )` function

[JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

A little [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8K9A/) to get you going

```
alert("Radio Mark " + $("#one").attr('mark') + ", Radio Value " + $("#one").attr('value'));

alert("check Mark " + $("#two").attr('mark') + ", check Value " + $("#two").attr('value'));
```

Comment: Anand, i have multiple elements with dynamic classes and ids. there is no fix id or class for any element.

Comment: Jut tell me how can i loop over the selected elements and get the required attribute's values

Comment: just use $(.each), the same way you have looped over data, same way you can loop over element. Use JSFiddle to play around with JQuery